# Should I choose for rsync or sftp?

Tags: sftp, rsync

I am trying to send huge (huge as in approx 5 gb) files between servers .. 
Which is better, sftp or rsync ?

Could someone point me to a comparison of sftp vs rsync if any available?

Is one better than the other? Why?

Comment: serverfault (http://serverfault.com/) might be a more appropriate forum for your question

Answer (score 4):

I would say use sftp cause rsyncs current hashing algorithm that the sender uses to find matches for moved data might cause problems with very large files. The current hash table has a fixed size of 65536 slots, and can get overloaded for really large files.
See a [discussion thread here.](http://www.mail-archive.com/rsync@lists.samba.org/msg17812.html)

Comment: that was good info :)

Answer (score 1):

If the files are text, rsync.  While @Thariama's point is valid, if they are similar you will get some bandwidth savings.  Just be careful with the switches the discussion mentions.

If the files are binary but have only segments changed, rsync.  I use this for VM images.